# Equivalence relation & partition definitions: IT goal or a mathematical motivation?

Tags: computer-science, order-theory

> For any equivalence relation on a set X, the set of its equivalence classes is a partition of X. Conversely, from any partition P of X, we can define an equivalence relation on X by setting x ~ y precisely when x and y are in the same part in P. Thus the notions of equivalence relation and partition are essentially equivalent. [Schechter 1997, p. 54.]

This seems obvious, but in truth, in my opinion it is not so easy. Say that "*from any partition P of X, we can define an equivalence relation on X by setting x ~ y precisely when x and y are in the same part in P*" for me is tautological and superficial conclusion because it is necessary to specify the reason why the definitions of "equivalence relation" (1) and "partition" (2) lead to define the first definition (1) from the second definition (2) or viceversa (from 2 to 1).

For example to talk about of partition we talk about of a **Setoid**. Often in mathematics, when one defines an equivalence relation on a set, one immediately forms the quotient set (turning equivalence into equality)

> a setoid (X, ~) is a set (or type) X equipped with an equivalence relation ~

But what is the real motivation to have setoids where the definition of partition and equivalence relation seem to 2 identical objects but only with different roles? 
For me, actually, "partition" and "equivalence relation" seem to be constructed to have and to ensure an access to the same object where setoid works as a partially ordered set whose ultimate goal is to generate not an ***order theory*** but a kind of abstract data type similar to **queues** used in computer science.
The definitions of "partition" and "equivalence relationship" do not seem to have been created to guarantee mathematical information, but an IT goal and for me these 2 definitions must be mathematically rewritten **to reclaim a mathematical motivation.**

Comment: Is there a question in here?

Comment: @MatthewDaly Question ask for what reason definitions of *partition* and *equivalence relation* it was built because for me the goal is not clear, seems not for a mathematical motivation.

Comment: Good mathematics books give absolutely precise definitions of (i) equivalence relation (ii) partition. If you think the statement you have highlighted is trivial you need to think again.

Comment: It? Like Pennywise the Dancing Clown?

Answer (score 4):

I honestly have no idea what your last paragraph is saying - what does it mean to "guarantee mathematical information"? what is "an IT goal"? what does it mean to "mathematically rewrite" something, or "reclaim a mathematical motivation"? - but there is a specific content question here which I can address. Namely:

**Partitions and equivalence relations are *not* identical**. They are "morally equivalent" - there is a canonical bijection, given a set $X$, between partitions of $X$ and equivalence relations on $X$ - but they're not literally the same:

- An equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$ is in particular a **relation**: a set of ordered pairs of elements of $X$. That is, an equivalence relation on $X$ is a subset of the Cartesian product $X^2$ (with certain properties).
- A partition $P$ of $X$ is a **set of subsets of $X$**. That is, a partition of $X$ is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ (with certain properties).

For a concrete example, take $$X=\{a,b,c\}.$$ Then $$\{\{a,b\},\{c\}\}$$ is a partition of $X$; the corresponding equivalence relation is $$\{\langle a,a\rangle, \langle b,b\rangle,\langle c,c\rangle, \langle a,b\rangle, \langle b,a\rangle\}$$ (where "$\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$" is your favorite [ordered pairing notion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function)). These are not the same object, even though in some sense they have the same "meaning."

So which is the "better" notion? Well, there isn't one - and this is a general phenomenon in mathematics: we often have multiple different formal notions corresponding to (more or less) the same idea, but without a single "optimal" one, since different circumstances can make different instantiations more or less natural.

Comment: Hey!  Don't tell me what my favorite ordered pairing notion is!

Comment: I think "canonical bijection" is spot-on. That's the crucial point, and imho it's very tedious to write out a careful proof.

Comment: @XanderHenderson "Pairing *notion*." :P

Comment: Indeed, corrected! :P  (+1, by the way.  This is, more or less, the answer that I was writing; you must type faster than I.)

Comment: @ancientmathematician   I guess you need some heavy ordinance (cannons?) to define a bijection between the partitions of an infinite set and the equivalence relations on it...

Comment: @CopyPasteIt Actually I disagree with ancientmathematician on this point - I think it's fairly straightforward. But maybe they have a particular stumbling point in mind?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I disagree re: tedium - do you have a point in mind that is particularly annoying? It seems straightforward to me (although I could easily be overlooking something which is a common stumbling block to many).

Comment: I really should've consulted with wikipedia b4 posting my comment. But his comment and the *pairing notion* stuff made me think I'm missing something. But OK - nothing fancy going on here. $\quad \{x,\{x,y\}\}$

Comment: But why the link to wikii *Pairing function*?

Comment: @CopyPasteIt Because it's a decent source on the topic, and it's worth knowing that there are *many* ways to implement ordered pairs in set theory (it really demystifies things in my opinion).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I find it difficult to fix upon a notation that doesn't become confusing as one proves that the equivalence relation induced by the partition induced by a given equivalence relation is the equivalence relation one first thought of. (And of course the other way round too.) I agree the proof is so "straightforward" that one could do it blindfold, but as I say for me tedium sets in. When teaching I found that this theorem was a modern Pons Asinorum.

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics, it is very useful to have different interpretations of the same concept, here the set of equivalence relations on a set $X$ corresponds one-to-one with the set of partitions of the set $X$.

Suppose you want to enumerate all equivalence relations of a finite set $X$. To approach this problem, it is easier to consider the set of all partitions of $X$. The number of all partitions of an $n$-set is the $n$th Bell number $B(n)$. Partitions of a set are easier to study  than relations with a ''sophisticated structure'' (reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity).